# Can the Pi check if someone is currently connected via ssh even if the connection did not got closed

Tags: python, linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, paramiko

Is it possible for a Raspberry Pi to check if someone is connected (and sends input) via ssh, even if the ssh connection (over Paramiko) did not get closed properly (the connection breaks off because the client is too far away for example)? Over w or who it's possible to see if a connection is still open but not if it's still active.

Comment: In addition to the answers that were already given you can also adjust some settings in `sshd_config` to have more control over when ssh closes the connection. Theser are `ClientAliveInterval`, `ClientAliveCountMax`, `ServerAliveInterval`, `ServerAliveIntervalMax` and `TCPKeepAlive`. The details depend on what you want to detect. Is it the connectivity between server and client, or do you care if the connection is temporarily down for 10 seconds, or do you care about how long it has been since the user has sent something, etc.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Sorry @jww, did not realize that, but the answers I got here are sufficient.

Comment: @mars I want to check the connection between client and server.

Answer (score 0):

The Unix `w` command will show you when a connection was established, and how long each person has been idle:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ $ w

07:52:13 up 1 day, 11:43,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
pi       tty1                      Sat19   36:35m  0.40s  0.34s -bash
pi       pts/0    192.168.1.113    Sat20    1.00s  0.53s  0.02s w
```

Answer (score -1):

I have some ways for you:

- *netstat -tn | grep 22* to ssh connection to/from your pi.

[image]

- If there are someone are connecting to your pi. You can use ***htop*** with tree display mode to see any bash sessions under ssh deamon ( **/usr/sbin/sshd -D** ). Like pic below:

[image]